# Replacing repeatedly occuring groups of an anchored regex in java

Tags: java, regex

Using Java 7 and the default RegEx implementatiin in java.util.regex.Pattern, given a regex like this:

`^start (m[aei]ddel[0-9] ?)+ tail$`

And a string like this:

`start maddel1 meddel2 middel3 tail`

Is it possible to get an output like this using the anchored regex:

`start <match> <match> <match> tail`.

I can get every group without anchors like this:

Regex: `m[aei]ddel[0-9]`

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement("<middle>"));
}
```

The problem is that I'm working on a quite big dataset and being able to anchor the patterns would be a huge performance win.

However when I add the anchors the only API that I can find requires a whole match and accessing the last occurrence of the group. I my case I need to verify that the regex actually matches (i.e. a whole match), but in the replacement step I need to be able to access every group on it's own.

*edit* I'd like to avoid workarounds like looking for the anchors in a separate step because it would require bigger changes to the code and wrapping it all up in RegExes feels more elegant.

Comment: Are you just replacing each `maddle` with `<middle>`?

Comment: yes, I don't think I have to do more tasks on the matched sequence

Comment: To clarify: `m[aei]ddel[0-9]` is just an example, my actual regexes are more complex and each regex will have a different replacement. The important point is that I need to replace every occurence of the matche's group with it's own replacement and the regex has to be anchored.

Comment: You could do it in two steps : match the anchored sentence, then replace the grouped words in that sentence.

Comment: Yeah, thought about this, just curious if there is an API to do it without separating the two steps (would allow local changes, whereas separating means a bigger change to the whole system down to the database where the regexes are stored)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it in one step, you need to use a `\G` based regex that will do the anchoring. However, you also need a positive lookahead to check if the string ends with the desired pattern.

Here is a regex that should work:

```
(^start|(?!\A)\G)\s+m[aei]ddel[0-9](?=(?:\s+m[aei]ddel[0-9])*\s+tail$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p6pZiV/1)

```
String s = "start maddel1 meddel2 middel3 tail";
String pat = "(^start|(?!\\A)\\G)\\s+(m[aei]ddel[0-9])(?=(?:\\s+m[aei]ddel[0-9])*\\s+tail$)";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(pat, "$1 <middle>" ));
```

See the [Java online demo](http://ideone.com/l0BA5x)

**Explanation**:

- `(^start|(?!\A)\G)` - match `start` at the end of string or the end of the previous successful match
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `m[aei]ddel[0-9]` - `m`, then either `a`, `e`, `i`, then `ddel`, then 1 digit
- `(?=(?:\s+m[aei]ddel[0-9])*\s+tail$)` - only if followed with:

  - `(?:\s+m[aei]ddel[0-9])*` - zero or more sequences of 1+ whitespaces and `middelN` pattern
  - `\s+`  - 1 or more whitespaces
  - `tail$`  - `tails` substring followed with the end of string.

Comment: Good call that anubhava's regex will match other input, too. A pity things get so much more complicated (syntax wise and requiring loop-arounds). I'll give it a try and hope my teammates can live with slightly more scary-looking regexes ;)

Comment: If you do not want to hard code white spaces, move the whitespace pattern into Group 1, see http://ideone.com/5nPrri. You still can use a two step approach by first chrcking the string with`"^start .* tail\\z"` and then replace what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\G` for this:

```
final String regex = "(^start |(?<!^)\\G)m[aei]ddel[0-9] (?=.* tail$)";
final String str = "start maddel1 meddel2 middel3 tail";

String repl = str.replaceAll(regex, "$1<match> ");
//=> start <match> <match> <match> tail
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DXv0ep/8)

`\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.

Comment: This regex will also find matches in a string like [`start maddel1 meddel2 middel3 something else tail`](https://regex101.com/r/G6OqBh/2)

Answer (score 2):

With the `\G` anchor, for the `find` method, you can write it this way:

```
pat = "\\G(?:(?!\\A) |\\Astart (?=(?:m[aei]ddel[0-9] )+tail\\z))(m\\S+)";
```

details:

```php
\\G # position after the previous match or at the start of the string
    # putting it in factor makes fail the pattern more quickly after the last match
(?:
    (?!\\A) [ ] # a space not at the start of the string
                # this branch is the first one because it has more chance to succeed
  |
    \\A start [ ] # "start " at the beginning of the string
    (?=(?:m[aei]ddel[0-9] )+tail\\z) # check the string format once and for all
                                     # since this branch will succeed only once
)
( # capture group 1
    m\\S+ # the shortest and simplest pattern that matches "m[aei]ddel[0-9]"
          # and excludes "tail" (adapt it to your need but keep the same idea)
)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/zqqY8I/1)

Comment: I frankly, like your solutions.